# Formula gives different results if radians or degrees are used?

Tags: classical-mechanics, units

The formula to describe the angle $\theta$ in a conical pendulum is:

$$
\theta = sin^{-1} \left( \frac{g}{l\omega^2}\right)
$$

This gives different results depending on if you use radians or degrees.

This is strange behaviour, how could you explain this?

Comment: this may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions "When measuring in radians, an angle of θ radians will correspond to an arc whose length is rθ, where r is the radius of the circle. Thus, in the unit circle, "the arc whose cosine is x" is the same as "the angle whose cosine is x", because the length of the arc of the circle in radii is the same as the measurement of the angle in radians.["

Comment: Also, when I measure my height the result comes out different depending on whether I use inches of centimeters.  How can we explain this?

Answer (score 3):

The function $\sin^{-1}{x}$ is defined as the angle in **radians** whose $\sin(\cdot)$ gives $x$ (within some chosen range of angles).

Answer (score 0):

The angle can be expressed in either degrees or radians. The numeric values are different, but both subtend the same arc.  Many formulas (especially in calculus) require that the angles be in radians.